# Почему при скролинге виснет сайт?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, есть сайт [платьехочу.рф/test/](http://%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%83.%D1%80%D1%84/test/), как только скоролишь к каруселе (owl carousel), то сайт нагулхо виснет и не реагирует ни на что. Со временем он начинает работать как надо
В консоли ошибок никаких не выводит. В чем может быть проблема?

```js
$('.item').magnificPopup({
  type: 'image',
  closeOnContentClick: true,
  mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
  image: {
    verticalFit: true
  }

});

$('.next').click(function() {
  owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
})
$('.prev').click(function() {

  owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel', [300]);

})
```

```html
<div class="owl-carousel">
  <a href='img/work/1.jpg' class="item">
    <img src="img/work/1.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href='img/work/2.jpg' class="item">
    <img src="img/work/2.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href='img/work/3.jpg' class="item">
    <img src="img/work/3.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href='img/work/4.jpg' class="item">
    <img src="img/work/4.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href='img/work/5.jpg' class="item">
    <img src="img/work/5.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href='img/work/6.jpg' class="item">
    <img src="img/work/6.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href='img/work/7.jpg' class="item">
    <img src="img/work/7.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href='img/work/8.jpg' class="item">
    <img src="img/work/8.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <a href='img/work/9.jpg' class="item">
    <img src="img/work/9.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
</div>
<div class="controlls">
  <div class="prev"></div>
  <div class="next"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Привет, добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском. Код для воспроизведения проблемы должен быть прямо в вопросе, такие уж у нас правила. Иначе вопрос получится "одноразовым", бесполезным всем будущим читателям. Так что попробуйте пожалуйста локализовать проблему. На сайте есть встроенные сниппеты, аналог jsfiddle, в них можно выполнять код JS-HTML-CSS прямо на странице.

Comment: Понял, код добавил

Comment: Завернул в сниппет, но чего-то ему не хватает. Какую-нибудь библиотеку подключить?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, какой-то `owl`, `jquery` и `magnificPopup` - это то, что на первый взгляд не достает

Comment: Я использовал owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com и https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup, jquery